# ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 552 failed

Tags: angular, typescript, migration, chunks, angular13

I am migrating the Angular 12 to 13, though the migration is successful but when I run project in the browser after successful build, It doesn't show the application. When I checked the console, it shows below error:

> ChunkLoadError: Loading chunk 552 failed.

Also, It shows 2 files are not found, but when I checked in `dist` folder, those files exists:

[image]

Below is the error log in `console`:

[image]

I am not sure why it is showing this errors. I tried multiple solutions from the `stackoverflow` but no luck.

`ng v`
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/22113#issuecomment-1004279867

I have to put following code in my `main.ts` file:

```
declare var  __webpack_public_path__: string;
__webpack_public_path__ = 'valueFormerlyAssignedUsing_deployUrl';
```

Replace `valueFormerlyAssignedUsing_deployUrl` with your path to folder containing chunks.

Answer (score 1):

Since your resource given was not sufficient to understand your situation, let me share my approach to get a picture of your concern.

1. Can you double check if you are still using the old version cli?
2. In **angular.json**, can you ensure that it aligns with the correct settings for angular 13, including **outputPath** and **publicPath** properties, that they are conrrectly configured?
3. Please delete **node_modules** folder and reinstall dependencies.
4. Please review the compiler options in the **tsconfig.json** file. Ensure that the **module** value is set to **es2020** or higher. This can help avoid compatibility issues with chunk loading.
5. If you are using a service worker or any caching mechanism, disable or clear the cache to ensure that the latest version of the application is being served.
6. Can you try alternative build tools like webpack directly to see if the issue persists.
7. If your app uses lazy loading, please disable it temporarily. This can help narrow down the cause of the problem.
8. Strongly recommend this: Create a new angular project. As a last resort, consider creating a new angular project with angular 13 and gradually migrate your code and dependencies to the new project. This can help isolate any configuration or compatibility issues that might be causing the problem.

Hope my approach would give you any hint to resolve the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can't found the `publicPath`  in `angular.json`. `outputPath'` is there! Added CLI screen-shot for your reference

Comment: `module` value is set to `es2020`

Comment: I checked this url: https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=12.0-13.0 and found below step:

`You can no longer specify lazy-loaded routes by setting a string value to loadChildren. Make sure you move to dynamic ESM import statements.`

Do you know what is the meaning of it?

Comment: `reinstalling dependencies` didn't help